# How to let a sprite call the sprite owner (layer) to remove the sprite when the sprite finishes its task?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a custom sprite derived from CCNode, and I want the sprite to be removed from the layer after the sprite detecting a signal, what technique should I use?
Is it safe to do `[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]` inside the sprite to kill itself? In such way I can do what I want, but it is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is generally safe to call `removeFromParentAndCleanup` from within the sprite object. When you do this, nothing particularly special happens to the sprite - the one thing that might cause problems is the fact that the `self.parent` will be nullified, so you should avoid calling on the sprite's parent after using `removeFromParentAndCleanup`.

Comment: sending messages to nil references is not an error but ignored in objective c